# Can anyone explain this code

Tags: python, twisted

Have a confusion , In the following code "gotProtocol" is passed to the callback function.while executing this with the sample server program,it could able to send those string with the method "sendMessage" which we registered in the class greeter . But HOW ?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint

class Greeter(Protocol):
    def sendMessage(self, msg):
        self.transport.write("MESSAGE %s\n" % msg)

class GreeterFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Greeter()

def gotProtocol(p):
    p.sendMessage("Hello")
    reactor.callLater(1, p.sendMessage, "This is sent in a second")
    reactor.callLater(2, p.transport.loseConnection)

point = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, "localhost", 1234)
d = point.connect(GreeterFactory())
d.addCallback(gotProtocol)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Where is it not creating an instance?

Comment: it is a callback function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

Comment: but why that  function "gotProtocol" does't have an argument when it got called ?

Comment: The function is never called (yet) in your example code. `gotProtocol` doesn't have parentheses after it, so it's just a variable.

Comment: this program could able to send those string  when i just excuted with the sample server program .. i am not sure how ?

Comment: In Python, a function is an object just like other objects. You can pass it around just as you'd pass around a string. If thinking of a function confuses you, think of it as if it were a string instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its asynchronous programming. It can be a little confusing at first. The basic idea is that you define functions and pass them to the library and it will execute them when it needs to.

`gotProtocol` is a callback function. `addCallback` is not calling it, the function is being passed as an argument and stored to be called later.

The variable `p` represents the value that will be passed when twisted calls your standalone function `gotProtocol` and will give the function context (i.e you will have something to operate on).

To show a very simple example of this

```
import time
# imagine this function is defined in a library
def libraryfunc(cb):
    time.sleep(1)
    cb(1)

# your callback function that will be called later by library
def mycb(i):
    print "the library returned me %d" % i

libraryfunc(mycb)
```

You pass the library a function and it will pass you something back later by calling that function.

`p` will be a `Greeter` instance. As `Greeter` inherits from `Protocol` it can be used [polymorphically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) as a `Protocol` object internally by twisted, but when you receive it you can call the extra method specific to the `Greeter` class `sendMessage` as well as the methods inherited from `Protocol` that will do the networky stuff e.g. `self.transport.write`.

As for how and when the `Greeter` instance is created. You provided a [factory class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that will return an instance of `Greeter` so twisted can create the instance when it needs to and return it to you in the callback. The advantage of the factory method is that twisted doesn't need to know the [concrete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29#Abstract_and_concrete) class it is instantiating, as long as the class inherits from `Protocol` its useable.

Comment: it can be used polymorphically as a Protocol object ? any example for this ?